# Combine data to one item and replace the out-range chars

Tags: sql-server

In my sql server, I have a table called "company" and data is as below photo. 
[image]

I use a query:
`STUFF((select ', ' + a.companyname from (select companyname from company) a FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 2, '')` to show the data with a row as below photo.
[image]

However, it is too long for me with this date and I would like to show data with max 40 chars. I can use LEFT(companyname,40) to show the result as below.

[image]

My question is: how can I replace the incomplete data with "..."?

[image]

Remarks: The length of some company name are different, may be long or short, and comma sign "," may also be included in some of company name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case when   len(@companyname) > 40
     then   left(@companyname, 40 - charindex(',', reverse(left(@companyname,40))) + 1) 
            + '..'
     else   @companyname
     end
```

if the company name may contain comma, consider using other character like ';' as delimiter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 CASE WHEN LEN(companyname) > 40 THEN LEFT(companyname,40) + '"..."'
      ELSE LEFT(companyname,40)
 END AS CompanyName
```